# Adding a Button to a column in TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, super

So, I am trying to add a button to a column using Table View in JavaFX. I have successfully created a single button for one column; using the same code to add another button on another column with a small change of variables is resulting me in one error which I am unable to fix. The error is that it is not allowing me to use the word super. Below is the code in which I am having the error on;

```
TableColumn<UserDetails, UserDetails> addColumn = column("Add", ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<UserDetails>::new, 50);

    addColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        TableCell<UserDetails, UserDetails> addCell = new TableCell<UserDetails, UserDetails>() {
            public void addItems(UserDetails userDetails, boolean empty) {
                super.addItems(userDetails, empty); //This line is the error (super)
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(addButton);
                }
            }

        };

        addButton.setOnAction(event -> add(addCell.getItem(), primaryStage));
        return addCell;
    });
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the `error` that you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [`TableCell` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html) there is no `addItems` method in `TableCell`. You probably wanted to use [the `updateItem` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem-T-boolean-):

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(UserDetails userDetails, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(userDetails, empty);
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I have done the updateItem method, so is there any way at all to add an "add Item" button to a column?

Comment: @Milan Of yourse you can add a `addItem` method to the class, but this doesn't mean it's added to `TableCell`. Furthermore the uses seem to be pretty limited, especially since you're using an anonymus class here, so the only way to access this method from outside of the anonymus class itself would be reflection.